# Modified python list

Tags: python, list

I have a function with two inputs the numeric and the threshold. I want to compute the boolean statement true if the numeric is greater than the threshold. Upon computing my code I get the following error message:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

See code:

```
num_list =([10, 1, 3, 7])
result =[]

def hits(num_list,threshold=5):
    
    for x in num_list:
        if threshold<num_list:
            return true
```

Comment: What do you think the line `num_list>7==True` does?

Comment: What is the purpose of the constant 4? What do you mean by "if a certain threshold is reached"? Do you mean if the threshold value occurs in the list?

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you are comparing an `int`, in this case, `threshold` with a list, `num_list` using the `<` operator, but that operation is not supported. Did you *intend* to use `x` instead of `num_list`?

Comment: you want `True`(uppercase) instead of true (lowercase - invalid name)
Are you sure you want to return True after only one value is above the threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through the for loop with `x`, but don't actually call `x` in the loop. Replace the conditional line with `if threshold<x` to access the variable `x` (int) instead of num_list (list). That's why you're getting the error about trying to compare an int and a list.